# add new window or view on the alertview click button in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uialertview

i juzz want to know that how we can add new window or view on the click of an alertview button in iphone?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your question is not clear. Do you want to add some subview to your current view upon clicking an alertview button ? or do you want to customize the alertview itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that from an AlertView since alertviews are meant only to display a specific alert not to take an action. I guess you better off using an ActionViews which is recommended by Apple if you want to perform a certain action from a model view in iphone.
Regards,

Comment: In action views you can have more than one button and you can assign actions to this buttons, so depending on what action you want to take you can do whatever you want including adding subViews or showing or hiding views ...

Comment: that also possible in alertview, i am using mainly two buttons  and will show in alertview. so i think i can also use alertview